# Sencha Touch2: Add check box to itemTpl

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch-2.1

Hi am new to Sencha touch2, am parsing url of json data and showing in list. How can i add check box for each listitem?

Answer (score 1):

Hi just add html to your template, try this:

```
itemTpl: '<input type="checkbox" id="myId" <tpl if="active">checked="checked"</tpl>/>{field from json data}',
```

Comment: Thanks. and how to get the checkbox checked value?

Comment: do you mean depending on data from json?
add "<tpl if="active">checked="checked"</tpl>" to the template.
each list item must have an "active" field that is true or false